# create J2me launcher

Tags: java-me, launcher

Hi I have to create J2me launcher in which when I run the emulator then icon is displayed when I click on it, then it will redirect me to the website which I have given. I have researched it on internet but I cannot find any solution Please if anyone can help me please help me and it there are any suggestions then give me.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use something like this:

```
platformRequest("http://ololo.com");
```

It will call a default browser to open the link.

Comment: No this is not the case. I need to create launcher in J2me same as launcher in android. But I can not create it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void openBrowser(String URL) {
        try {
            mainMIDlet.platformRequest(URL);
        } catch (ConnectionNotFoundException e) {
            // error
        }
    }
```